# Check if file is readable with Python: try or if/else?

Tags: python, if-statement, try-catch

I have the following code:

```
import glob, os
for file in glob.glob("\\*.txt"):
    if os.access(file, os.R_OK):
        # Do something
    else:
        if not os.access(file, os.R_OK):
            print(file, "is not readable")
        else:
            print("Something went wrong with file/dir", file)
        break
```

But I'm not entirely sure if this the right way to do it. Is it better to use `try` and `catch` the error? If so, how do I *try* for readability? Note the `break` in my else statement. As soon as a file can't be read I want to abort the loop.

Comment: You could try opening the file for reading and catching the resulting exception (if any). That would also be more robust than your current approach, since the file can become unreadable (or even disappear) between the two calls to `os.access()`.

Comment: Are you actually reading the file in the `# Do something` section or do you _only_ want to test its readability?

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm actually reading the file there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For me, using a try-except at the same scope as one would use an if-else gains no readability. The value of exceptions is that they can be caught at a higher level in the call tree.

Moving out just one level, we avoid the `break` statement:

```
import glob, os
try:
    for file in glob.glob("\\*.txt"):
        with open(file) as fp:
            # do something with file
except IOError:
    print("could not read", file)
```

But the true genius of exceptions is when the code simply disappears:

```
# Operate on several files
# SUCCESS: Returns None
# FAIL: Raises exception
def do_some_files():
    for file in glob.glob("\\*.txt"):
        with open(file) as fp:
            # do something with file
```

Now it is the calling program's responsibility to display a useful error message on failure. We have removed responsibility for dealing with failure completely out of this code and into a whole other realm.

In fact, one can move the responsibility completely out of our program and into the interpreter. In that case, the interpreter will print some useful error message and terminate our program. If Python's default message is good enough for your users, I recommend not checking for errors *at all*. Thus, your original script becomes:

```
import glob, os
for file in glob.glob("\\*.txt"):
    # Do something
```

Comment: Your kung-fu is better, have to admit.

Comment: As an answer to your last suggestion, wouldn't the interpreter then skip unreadable files rather than halting the loop and stopping? Because we never define what we need to do when an error occurs

Comment: No, @BramVanroy, the final short script would not skip unreadable files. The presumed `open()` inside `#Do Something` would raise an exception when trying to open an unreadable file. This exception would be caught by the interpreter which would print an error message and exit. That is, not coincidentally, precisely what the program in your question does:  print an error message and exit. The only difference between the behavior of my short version and your long version is the text of the error message.

Comment: I figured that, considering the code loops file per file, an error would be thrown but the loop wouldn't be halted. It's good to know that it *is* the case. Thanks.

Comment: @Robᵩ - You point out that error handling code is reduced by leaving it to the caller or even the interpreter, but doesn't lack of context become a problem? If a file isn't readable, and you catch the exception more than a few levels up, how can you know enough context to deal with it or even report it without having to dump the stack trace?

Comment: In practice, no, lack of context is not a problem. If a file is unreadable and you allow the interpreter to print the error message, the user sees this: `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'foo.txt'`. There is nothing about that error that is sensitive to the local context. Typically the response to such an event is to abort the program. However, if there *is* a context-sensitive response (like, try reading some other file, or reconstruct the file from defaults, or whatever), then you should catch the error locally. @ScottSmith

Comment: What about an error like `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'XXXAF1D4.TMP'`? That's a temp file from one of 20 different functions that were called. How can you know what failed without context?

Comment: I may not know the python way here, but if you can successfully open the file but trigger an exception when reading, shouldn't you try/catch that in a place where you can close the file? We can't expect the calling function to know to close files (particularly if it doesn't have the file pointer for them.)

Comment: @JeffreyGoldberg - Not really, for several reasons. 1) If you use the `with open() as fd` syntax, the file will be closed upon exiting the `with` block, regardless of how it is exited. 2) if you store the file object as a local, the interpreter will close the file when the stack frames that reference it are destroyed by the exception handler, and 3) the OS will close the file when the process exits. The only case I can imagine catching the exception is if the IO failure during `read` requires some non-standard cleanup (say, it is a device file and `.close()` doesn't sufficiently reset it.)

Answer (score 52):

A more explicit way to check if `file` is actually a file and not directory for example, and it is readable:

```
from os import access, R_OK
from os.path import isfile

file = "/some/path/to/file"

assert isfile(file) and access(file, R_OK), \
       f"File {file} doesn't exist or isn't readable"
```

Comment: I prefer this method even if it leaves room for the file to disappear or change before you open it.

Comment: Beware, the assert line is not executed if Python is executed in optimized mode by passing the -O option (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assert)

Comment: good point on `assert`, this was just a demonstration, you could change to an `if` statement.

Answer (score 10):

In Python culture, it's more common to [ask forgiveness, not permission](https://eventil.com/talks/KKS3G1-alex-martelli-permission-or-forgiveness), so it's preferable to catch the exception:

```
for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    try:
        with open(filename) as fp:
            # work with the file

    except IOError as err:
        print "Error reading the file {0}: {1}".format(filename, err)
        break
```

That way you will also avoid any double-checks or race conditions.

Comment: The `ask forgiveness, not permission` link is broken.

Comment: @Gautam replaced with the same author's same talk from 2012.

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
        # check to see if file is readable
        with open(filename) as tempFile:





except Exception as e:
        print e
        # here you can modify the error message to your liking
```

This is usually what I do.
It is robust and straight forward

Comment: Oops that issue should be addressed now

Comment: Never ever use an "except Exception" without straight "raise" just after !