# FastText Error! ValueError: (file-name) cannot be opened for training

Tags: nlp, fasttext

I Have installed fasttext module in Python and loaded the model [ 'cc.en.300.bin'].

I already made the data frame format according to the fasttext. and then generating the files

```
train.to_csv(" ecomm.train",columns=['Category_description'], index= False, header= False)
test.to_csv("ecom.test", columns=['Category_description'], index= False, header= False)
```

the files created successfully! then when I run this code

```
import fasttext

mod= fasttext.train_supervised(input='ecomm.train')
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rosie/Documents/ProGraMinG/Python/pythonProject/FastText/FastText_overview.py", line 97, in <module>
    mod= fasttext.train_supervised(input='ecomm.train')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fasttext/FastText.py", line 533, in train_supervised
    fasttext.train(ft.f, a)
ValueError: ecomm.train cannot be opened for training!
```

{ UPDATE } !!!

- Used both  `isfile()` and `exists()` functions to check if the file exists:

```
path = 'Users/rosie/Documents/ProGraMinG/Python/pythonProject/FastText/ecomm.train'

check_file = os.path.isfile(path)

print("isfile method ",check_file)
```

```
check_file = os.path.exists(path)

print("exists method  ",check_file)
```

Both methods returns ' False '.

- I also checked if the file is readable or not

```
doc= open(' ecomm.train', 'r')
print('checking if the file is readable', doc.readable())
```

However, it returned 'True', now I'm confused. As for the size of the ' ecomm.train', it is 29.4 MB

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the file is readable, at the simple (local) path `'ecomm.train'`, from your Python process, given its current local orking directory?

For example, try specifying the file as its full absolute path – on MacOS probably something like `/Users/yourusername/yourdirectory/etc/etc/ecomm.train`. If that works, the problem was that your Python code's effective directory wasn't what you expected.

Alternatively, if the process that wrote the file was in some way a different user than the later process trying to read it, there might be permission errors.

Totally separate from `fasttext`, you could check, from the same code that's about to try `fasttext` operations, if the file is readable (via either the local path, or the absolute path) using a recipe lie that in this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44213239/130288

Even if it fails, it might give a more-explanatory error.

Comment: so you are suggesting that I create a path for it? for now, i have placed these files in the same directory/folder as my project

Comment: No; first try the non-relative, 'absolute' path that describes entirely where the file is, maybe  starting with something like `/Users/rosie/Documents/ProGraMinG/Python/pythonProject/` if you're on MacOS. Does that work?

Comment: I got you now, I will try it and get back with the result

Comment: Yes, that will confirm if the main problem is just a mismatch between where the Python interpreter thinks its current working directory is, and your use of a purely-local (simple filename) path. If absolute works, you can use that, or check other things to either (a) change the working-dir; (b) use a correct relative path (maybe something like `project/myfile` or `../../myfile` etc). But if absolute *doesn't* work, maybe there's another problem.

Comment: Back again! using the absolute path, did not work ( gave me the same error), then I tested the file to see if it is readable by python or there is something with it  and it gave me ' True', python can read it.

Comment: Please show (by editing your question) the exact code and path you used to test the file's readability, and the result. Did you perform this test from inside your `/Users/rosie/Documents/ProGraMinG/Python/pythonProject/FastText/FastText_overview.py` file? (You should, to be sure conditions are identical to those where you're having the original problem.) How large is the `ecomm.train` file?

Comment: question is updated with the attempts!